# Node.js: Express set the "trust proxy" for CloudFront

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cloudfront

I have a [Express](https://expressjs.com/) backend behind [AWS Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). How properly set [trust proxy](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) for AWS Cloud Front:

```
app.set('trust proxy', function (ip) {
  if ( ???????????? ) return true; // trusted IPs
  else return false;
});
```

AWS Cloudfront use tons of ip address and is insecure validate all AWS ip address because anyone with an AWS EC2 instance have a valid IP.

Comment: You can add a [custom header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem

As you mentioned AWS CloudFront uses a long list of IP Address **ranges**.  It's mentioned [in their documenation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html).  You can see them via this one liner ([source](https://jonmoblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/19/how-to-unblock-your-cdn-and-detect-your-real-visitors/), requires `jq` which you can get from `brew` in MacOs.):

```sh
curl 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json' | jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.service=="CLOUDFRONT") | .ip_prefix'
```

(Update: or directly from http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips as mentioned [in their doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html).)

Right now, April 2021, it is giving me 122 ranges.

### The Solution

You can make an AJAX call to this file in Node, parse the JSON file, get the list as an array of string (`cloudFrontIps`), and pass that to `app.set('trust proxy', ['loopback', ...cloudFrontIps])`.

#### Good news!

The good news is someone else has already done it!  Check https://github.com/nhammond101/cloudfront-ip-ranges out.

### Final Notes

1. It's obvious, but worth mentioning that getting this list in asynchronous!  So, you might want to delay (e.g. `await`) your app start until this list is available.  It's not a must though -- calling `app.set` after the HTTP server is up should work, thought for that short duration you will be recording CloudFront's IP.
2. You might want to call this file and get the new list periodically.  The package is suggesting every 12 hours, using `setTimeout`.
3. My understanding is calling `app.set` on a running server will make the new list applicable on future calls immediately, without needing to restart.  I am getting this impression by how `X-Forward-For` is [examined on every request](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L306-L324), and how `app.set` is [calling](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/application.js#L352-L384) [`compileTrust` function](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/utils.js#L220-L239) on it's invocation. **So, TL;DR: You shouldn't be needing to restart the server every 12 hours for this!**
4. I look at express's code and it seems like `app.set` overrides (and not appends) the list every time you call it.  So if you have some IPs of your own (e.g. your `VPC's CIDR` in AWS ELB), you have to manually add it to the list every time you call this `app.set` in your `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

[Since the 1st of June 2022](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/limit-access-to-your-origins-using-the-aws-managed-prefix-list-for-amazon-cloudfront/) there is the CloudFront managed prefix list. It's a list of all the origin-facing CF IPs managed by AWS, [which you can utilise for both security groups and route tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-aws-managed-prefix-lists.html#use-aws-managed-prefix-list).

This way you can allow only CloudFront to access your resource on a network level. Doing this allows you to safely use `app.set('trust proxy', 1) // or 2 in case there is an alb in between the instance and CloudFront`, as you guarantee there is a consistent amount of hops (which are controlled by you) between "client" and server.

Caution: of course this doesn't hold true if you also consume your api from within your VPC through means other than the internet.

As an additional benefit you get [increased DDOS protection](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/limit-access-to-your-origins-using-the-aws-managed-prefix-list-for-amazon-cloudfront/).